# Tuplas separadas por virgulas

Tags: sql

Estou fazendo uma `query` no banco de dados (mysql) onde tenho um código e por este código existe vários tipos de pessoas.

Preciso que quando fizer a `query` venha assim

```
ID | NOMES
1  | Fulano 1, Fulano 2, Fulano 3
2  | Fulano 2, Fulano 4
3  | Fulano 5
```

Hoje faço a seguinte query:

```
select DESP.codTipoDespesa as codigo, DESP.descTipoDespesa as descricao, VALOR.valor as valor, DEPT.nome as nome
FROM
    (
    select codTipoDespesa, descTipoDespesa from despesas
    ) DESP
  LEFT JOIN
    (
      select codTipoDespesa, sum(valorDespesa) as valor FROM despesas GROUP BY codTipoDespesa
    ) VALOR
  ON DESP.codTipoDespesa = VALOR.codTipoDespesa
  LEFT JOIN
    (
      select idPessoa, valorDespesa, codTipoDespesa from despesas ORDER BY valorDespesa DESC
    ) CDEP
  ON DESP.codTipoDespesa = CDEP.codTipoDespesa
  LEFT JOIN
   (
       select id, nome from pessoa
   )  DEPT
ON DEPT.id = CDEP.idPessoa
GROUP BY DESP.codTipoDespesa
ORDER BY valor desc
```

Ai preciso que o resultado seja assim:

```
codigo | descricao | valor | nome
32     | Lapiseira | 3000  | Robertino Algusto, Felipe Abril, Ronaldo, Pedro,Gabriel
34     | Borracha  | 200   | Felipe Abril,Cintia , Martilucia, Joaozinho, Amanarque
```

Estrutura das tabelas:

```
PESSOAS
-------------------------------
numero         | AUTOINCREMENT
id             | text
nome           | text
partido        | text
tagLocalizacao | text
--------------------------------
DESPESAS
--------------------------------
numero          | AUTOINCREMENTO
idPessoa        | text
codTipoDespesas | text
mesDespesa      | text
descTipoDespesa | text
valorDespesa    | text
---------------------------------
```

> Preciso mostrar a listagem do gasto total por categoria no ano de 2015 ordenados do maior para o menor; [valor despesas somado a cada mês] - Isto ja estou fazendo em minha query.
>   Ai para cada categoria desta preciso pegar as pessoas que mais gastou
>
> Ex de tuplas das tabelas de despesas
>
> numero | idPessoa | codDespesas | mês | descricao | valor
>
> 1      | 12193    | 34          |  2  |   Lapiz   | 6485

Além disto tenho que mostrar os id dos 5 primeiros.

Achei este documento [aqui](http://csharpbrasil.com.br/como-retornar-mais-de-um-valor-separados-por-virgula-em-um-subselect/), é exatamente o que quero porém não estou sabendo como fazer, alguem pode me ajudar ?

> Com a query que tenho utilizado ele me retorna apenas o ultimo nome, preciso que retorne os 5 últimos e separados por virgulas.
>   Como fazer isto direto da sql ?

Comment: Em qual banco de dados?

Comment: estou fazendo no sqlite, porém a query é do mysql

Comment: irei incrementar a pergunta para demonstra como faço para entender melhor

Comment: @rray Atualizei minha pergunta

Comment: @rray Teria como me ajudar baseado no documento que coloquei ? Não estou sabendo criar solução

Comment: Amigo coloca sua estrutura do banco na sua questão, estou achando que da pra simplificar bastante a query que está usando, só não entendi ainda a estrutura do banco.

Comment: @Euler01 Atualizei

Comment: @Euler01 algum parecer sobre ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No `MySQL` você pode utilizar a função `GROUP_CONCAT` para fazer isso, no seu caso ficaria assim

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DEPT.nome SEPARATOR ', ') as nome
```

Essa função serve para agrupar sua string por um delimitador desejado, quando você utiliza algum agrupamento.

Você pode ler mais a respeito dela nesse link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html